# How to redirect output to a log file from cron and prepend timestamp?

Tags: bash, cron, logs, timestamps, macintosh

Most logs on my Mac have a time stamp before the output message like this:

`Nov 14 17:55:24 - SoftRAID Driver: SoftRAID driver loaded, version 5.8.1.`

I am running an executable in cron and instead of using mail I want to output all info to a log file and add a timestamp to each line in front of the output. I am using `>>` to append to a single file.

This is my crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
MAILTO=""
* 6-23 * * * /usr/local/bin/urlwatch >> /Users/john/cronjobs/urlwatch.log
```

This is what I get in urlwatch.log

```
UNCHANGED: (01)urlwatch update released (https://github.com/thp/urlwatch/releases/latest)
```

How do I make the output look like this:

```
Nov 14 17:55:24 - UNCHANGED: (01)urlwatch update released (https://github.com/thp/urlwatch/releases/latest)
```

I have tried many different suggestions from across the web and have had no luck. If saving to a text file is easier that will work as well.

Tried this which is close:

```
* 6-23 * * * (date && /usr/local/bin/urlwatch)  >> /Users/john/cronjobs/urlwatch.log
```

Output in the log file looks like this:

```
Sun Mar 15 13:35:00 CDT 2020
UNCHANGED: (03)RansomWhere? Objective-See (https://objective-see.com/products/ransomwhere.html)
UNCHANGED: (01)urlwatch update released (https://github.com/thp/urlwatch/releases/latest)
UNCHANGED: (02)urlwatch webpage (https://thp.io/2008/urlwatch/)
```

Comment: Does your system provide the `ts` command?

Comment: I have `urlwatch 2.17` and `unchanged: true` in `$HOME/.urlwatch/urlwatch.yaml` and every time I run `urlwatch` it shows whole HTML code of the page and 2x UNCHANGED lines: `01. UNCHANGED: https://github.com/thp/urlwatch/releases/latest` and `UNCHANGED: https://github.com/thp/urlwatch/releases/latest`. Do you mean you *always* get a single line that says `UNCHANGED: (01)urlwatch update released (https://github.com/thp/urlwatch/releases/latest)`?

Comment: @steeldriver "-bash: ts: command not found". I could add via homebrew saw this on AppleStackExchange: "Try brew install moreutils and then run the ts command."

Comment: @steeldriver ts installed. What do you suggest?

Comment: ... so you should be able to do something like `/usr/local/bin/urlwatch  | /path/to/ts >> /Users/john/cronjobs/urlwatch.log` (I don't know what `/path/to/` is for homebrew installed executables)

Comment: @steeldriver OK that works! Except it keeps the timestamp for each line the same. I tried to use the ```-i``` flag but had strange output.

Comment: The lines will have the same timestamp if they are written at the same time - perhaps that's simply because `urlwatch` is buffering its output?

Comment: % signs must be escaped for the same reason as discussed here [How can I execute `date` inside of a cron tab job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job)

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you. That was the issue. Please add these comments as the answer so I can vote for it. ```urlwatch``` is definitely buffering its output. Time is exactly the same for each line including milliseconds. Not sure of a way around this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105590/discussion-between-john-and-steeldriver).

Comment: Aha!  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/559801/5132 again, except that it's MacOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have (or can obtain, from *homebrew* for example) the `ts` **t**ime**s**tamp utility, then you should be able to do something like

```
/usr/local/bin/urlwatch | /path/to/ts >> /Users/john/cronjobs/urlwatch.log
```

(`/path/to/ts` would typically be `/usr/bin/ts` on Linux systems; it may be another location on OSX). From `man ts`:

> ```
> DESCRIPTION
>        ts adds a timestamp to the beginning of each line of input.
> ```

If you want to specify a non-default time format then you can do so but remember that the `%` sign has special significance in `cron` and must be escaped. See for example

- [How can I execute `date` inside of a cron tab job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job)

You may find that groups of lines are given the same timestamp - that *may* be because the program that is generating them is buffering its output. If either the `unbuffer` or `stdbuf` utilities is available for your system, it *may* be possible to enforce line-buffering as described here:

- [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)

Comment: @JdeBP While I accepted the answer using ```ts``` as the solution it would have been better if we had found a solution using OS X native tools.